# How to merge Dynamic Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm looking for help to add two dynamically generated dataframes.
Both DataFrames have a column computed on input from an intslider ipywidget. 
the third Dataframe should update dynamically on changes of any of above Dataframes

```py
import pandas as pd
from ipywidgets import interact
```

```py
@interact(x=(0,1000,10))
def df_draw_one(x):
    data = {"A":[1,2,3,4,5]}
    df_one = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_one['B'] = df_one['A']*x
    print(df_one)
```

```py
@interact(x=(0,1000,10))
def df_draw_two(x):
    data = {"A":[6,7,8,9,10]}
    df_two = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_two['B'] = df_two['A']*x
    print(df_two)
```

```py
df_res = df_one+df_two
```

I understand with the current code, df_one and two are local and hence result in:

> NameError: name 'df_one' is not defined

but I'm at loss on how to make them accessible. 
Any pointer would be appreciated

Comment: return `df_one` and `df_two` not print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your functions return the two dataframe adding a `return` statement.

```
import pandas as pd
from ipywidgets import interact


@interact(x=(0, 1000, 10))
def df_draw_one(x):
    data = {"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
    df_one = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_one['B'] = df_one['A'] * x
    print(df_one)
    return df_one


@interact(x=(0, 1000, 10))
def df_draw_two(x):
    data = {"A": [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
    df_two = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_two['B'] = df_two['A'] * x
    print(df_two)
    return df_two


df_one = df_draw_one(1)
df_two = df_draw_two(1)

df_res = df_one + df_two
print(df_res)
```

Another way is to have `df_one` and `df_two` as global variables, but it's dirty and not really necessary.

**Update**
One idea could be to have both widget generated in the same function, then everything becomes more easy to handle.

```
import pandas as pd
from ipywidgets import interact


@interact()
def df_draw_one(x=(0, 1000, 10), y=(0, 1000, 10)):

    data = {"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
    df_one = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_one['B'] = df_one['A'] * x

    data2 = {"A": [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
    df_two = pd.DataFrame(data2)
    df_two['B'] = df_two['A'] * y

    display(df_one)
    display(df_two)
    df_res = df_one + df_two
    display(df_res)
```

Here my result:

[image: Here my result]

Comment: I had that one at some point. 
the catch is that x in both dataframes df_res is set to x.

Comment: (appending to previous comment)
`
    A   B
0   7   7
1   9   9
2  11  11
3  13  13
4  15  15
`

Comment: do understand better, you want both the df to be controlled by the same slider?

Comment: good question. no. i want both df's to be independably adjustable, and df_res should dynamically update on any individual changes of df_one or df_two

Comment: I think if you put both in the same function everything become more easy :)

Comment: thanks a lot! your update is *exactly* what i was looking for. works like a charm. there's heavy flickering while dragging the sliders, but that's (for now) neglectable. KUDOS

Comment: You welcome, I am using SO questions as an opportunity to learn more Python, about the flickering you can take a look at the [documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html#Flickering-and-jumping-output).